# Problems installing PySide2

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, pyside2

I am totally new to PySide. Trying to install PySide2 on Ubuntu 18.04 by following steps provided [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/gettingstarted-linux.html).

Command:

```
$python setup.py build --qmake=/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake --build-tests --ignore-git --parallel=8 --internal-build-type=shiboken2
```

Output:

```
[ 19%] Linking CXX static library ../tests/libapiextractor.a
[ 19%] Built target apiextractor
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
error: Error compiling shiboken2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 296, in <module>
    setup_runner.run_setup()
  File "/home/omkark/pyside-setup/build_scripts/setup_runner.py", line 158, in run_setup
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: 
setup.py invocation failed with exit code: 1.
```

Could anyone please suggest how to resolve this?